# How does compiler converts return value into return Task<value> in async methods?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, .net-core, async-await

I've designed the following method to create records.

```
public Task<Guid> NotAwaited()
{
  Account account = new Account();
  Context.Accounts.Add(account);
  Context.SaveChangesAsync();
  return new Task<Guid>(() => account.Id);
}
```

Then, I realized that there's risk of the saving not being finished at the moment of returning the guid. So I've added `await`, which required me to decorate the method signature with `async`. Upon that, I got an error demanding a simpler syntax of what's being returned, like this.

```
public async Task<Guid> Awaited()
{
  Account account = new Account();
  Context.Accounts.Add(account);
  await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
  return account.Id;
}
```

I understand that the `account.Id` part gets converted to a task somehow. I'm just uncertain how. It feel like if it's black magic (which I understand it isn't).

Is there an implicit conversion? Or am I still performing the asynchronous call improperly?

Comment: It's happy to auto-wrap the guid you're returning into a Task.

Comment: Short answer: the compiler *does* some black magic to convert the return type into a `Task<TReturn>`. Long answer involves understanding how the compiler generates the state machines that have to be created by using `await`

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils OK, that makes me more at ease. However, since it's auto-wrapping the stuff into a task, how can/should I control the success status? In the actual code, there's a scenario where I want the task to be failed and in the consuming controller in the API produce either `Ok(guid)` or `NotFound(guid)`...

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Thanks, mate. At the moment I'm happy with the short version. However, since it's automagical behavior, I wonder how I can control the status of success of the task then. Please see the comment I've made above for the actual use case description.

Comment: That's the good part, you just *don't care*. You know that after you call `var result = await Awaited();` you *will* have a Guid (or an exception, should that happen)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Aha. You are saying that in the scenario that's supposed to communicate a failure in the service, I should throw up not return a null'ish guid. Isee - I'm going to give it a whack immediately.

Comment: You can: 1: return null (change return to `Task<guid?>`) and handle flow by null checks, 2: throw an exception and handle flow that way (ugh), or 3: create a `ServiceResponse` class that gives you `bool Result;` and `T Data;` (data returned in case of success), this is a very common pattern

Comment: I'd say, ideally, you'd want to stay within the task pipeline as long as possible. Exceptional behavior can be encapsulated within the task. A `Task<T>` is an "elevated/lifted type" and its properties can be used to skip further processing of a failed task for example without manually throwing exceptions and such.

Comment: @SOusedtobegood I like #3 the best because it seems most object oriented and organized. Also, since it seems to be so common patter to use a class alike `ServiceResponse`-thingy, I'm surprised that there's no such default, out-of-the-box class in the framework already. Or is there such a thing I simply suck at finding it?!

Comment: @SOusedtobegood Unrelated question - what's up with the nick of yours? Some kind of message or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of `async` as wrapping results (both return values and exceptions) into a `Task<T>`.

Likewise, `await` unwraps the results (extracting the return value or raising an exception).

I have an [`async` intro](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) that goes into more detail, and I recommend [`async` best practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) as followup to that. On a side note, [you should never use the `Task` constructor](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html).

Answer (score 2):

> It feel like if it's black magic

It probably is [sufficiently advanced to be indistinguishable from magic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarke%27s_three_laws).

You write C# code that the compiler then splits into pieces that run together and creates a state machine that "moves forward" every time an awaited asynchronous task completes. If you debug your code, the debugger knows how to represent the "local variables" (which may actually be instance members on a state machine type) in the debugger and map to the line of your original source code.

So for your case, the code could look something like (created via sharplab, see [this gist](https://sharplab.io/#gist:2b5dc1740716213186b4e1fe89596b2e)):

```
[AsyncStateMachine(typeof(<Awaited>d__0))]
public Task<Guid> Awaited()
{
    <Awaited>d__0 stateMachine = default(<Awaited>d__0);
    stateMachine.<>t__builder = AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<Guid>.Create();
    stateMachine.<>1__state = -1;
    AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<Guid> <>t__builder = stateMachine.<>t__builder;
    <>t__builder.Start(ref stateMachine);
    return stateMachine.<>t__builder.Task;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Auto)]
[CompilerGenerated]
private struct <Awaited>d__0 : IAsyncStateMachine
{
    public int <>1__state;

    public AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<Guid> <>t__builder;

    private Account <account>5__2;

    private TaskAwaiter <>u__1;

    private void MoveNext()
    {
        int num = <>1__state;
        Guid id;
        try
        {
            TaskAwaiter awaiter;
            if (num != 0)
            {
                <account>5__2 = new Account();
                Context.Accounts.Add(<account>5__2);
                awaiter = Context.SaveChangesAsync().GetAwaiter();
                if (!awaiter.IsCompleted)
                {
                    num = (<>1__state = 0);
                    <>u__1 = awaiter;
                    <>t__builder.AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted(ref awaiter, ref this);
                    return;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                awaiter = <>u__1;
                <>u__1 = default(TaskAwaiter);
                num = (<>1__state = -1);
            }
            awaiter.GetResult();
            id = <account>5__2.Id;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            <>1__state = -2;
            <>t__builder.SetException(exception);
            return;
        }
        <>1__state = -2;
        <>t__builder.SetResult(id);
    }

    void IAsyncStateMachine.MoveNext()
    {
        //ILSpy generated this explicit interface implementation from .override directive in MoveNext
        this.MoveNext();
    }

    [DebuggerHidden]
    private void SetStateMachine(IAsyncStateMachine stateMachine)
    {
        <>t__builder.SetStateMachine(stateMachine);
    }

    void IAsyncStateMachine.SetStateMachine(IAsyncStateMachine stateMachine)
    {
        //ILSpy generated this explicit interface implementation from .override directive in SetStateMachine
        this.SetStateMachine(stateMachine);
    }
}
```

You can see that the party where `SaveChangesAsync()` is called is located in a different logical branch than where the access to the Id property is. The local variable `account` is now the `<account>5__2` field on the generated struct. None of the identifier names used is actually a valid C# identifier, but is valid in the underlying IL language that is compiled to, the above code is a decompiled C#-ish representation of the code that is actually generated.

Calls to the `Awaited()` method will actually create new instances of the "hidden" `<Awaited>d__0` struct (in debug mode it will be a `class` instead of a `struct` to support edit-and-continue) and use types of the async infrastructure to wire this state machine up and run it.

`MoveNext()` is called when starting the state machine but also each time that an awaited task completes (as a continuation). You can see that the last part sets the result to the `id` value, which is basically your `return` statement.

Noteworthy to mention is that there is also a try-catch around most of the code which wraps exceptions into the task result - so you can `throw` in your code (or code called from your code) and it ends up creating a failed task instead of an unhandled exception when the asynchronous part of the method is scheduled.