# What happens to the top-level async caller's thread?

Tags: c#, async-await

I've experimented with a few things about `async`/`await` in C#. If we have an `async void` function that is called at the top level of our program and it takes more time than the rest of the program to finish, anything in that `async void` function is never called. I guess it is because the application thread has finished its job and OS just cleans everything up about our program (question 1: I'm not sure if its true, if I'm wrong can you correct me please?). See this code sample:

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("before M");
    Delay();
    Console.WriteLine("after M");
}

async void Delay()
{
    Console.WriteLine("before D1");
    await Task.Delay(100);
    Console.WriteLine("after D1 - 1 ");
    await Task.Delay(100);
    Console.WriteLine("after D1 - 2");
    await Task.Delay(100);
    Console.WriteLine("after D1 - 3");
    await Task.Delay(100);
    Console.WriteLine("after D1 - last");
}

Main();

Console.WriteLine("exited main");
```

The code above outputs this:

```
before M
before D1
after M
exited main
```

But if I modify it a little bit so that the main thread is still alive while our async tasks are being ran then we get this:

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("before M");
    Delay();
    Console.WriteLine("after M");
}

async void Delay()
{
    Console.WriteLine("before D1");
    await Task.Delay(100);
    Console.WriteLine("after D1 - 1 ");
    await Task.Delay(100);
    Console.WriteLine("after D1 - 2");
    await Task.Delay(100);
    Console.WriteLine("after D1 - 3");
    await Task.Delay(100);
    Console.WriteLine("after D1 - last");
}

Main();
while (true)
{
}

Console.WriteLine("exiting application");
```

The code above outputs this:

```
before M
before D1
after M
after D1 - 1
after D1 - 2
after D1 - 3
after D1 - last
```

First of all what actually happens in the first example (still about question 1). What happens to all those async tasks (What I said about them are just my assumptions, this is question 2).

Let's modify this code a little bit more:

```
async Task Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("before M");
    await Delay();
    Console.WriteLine("after M");
}

async Task Delay()
{
    Console.WriteLine("before D1");
    await Task.Delay(100);
    Console.WriteLine("after D1 - 1 ");
    await Task.Delay(100);
    Console.WriteLine("after D1 - 2");
    await Task.Delay(100);
    Console.WriteLine("after D1 - 3");
    await Task.Delay(100);
    Console.WriteLine("after D1 - last");
}

await Main();

Console.WriteLine("exiting application");
```

The code above also outputs this:

```
before M
before D1
after D1 - 1
after D1 - 2
after D1 - 3
after D1 - last
after M
exiting application
```

Now what happens to the application/main thread when it hits the first `Task.Delay` (question 3). As far as I know it should just abandon that thread to free resources and wait for a signal when that task is completed but that cannot happen because if that happens then the application just exists with code 0 (again it's my assumption about the exit code. Truthfulness of this assumption is question 4). So what happens to this thread? What happens to the TOP-LEVEL caller of an async functions thread? Who signals the thread that the task is done and who is listening for this signal and how? (question 5 which contains these three questions).

Comment: `should just abandon that thread` - [there is no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html). `Who signals the thread` - there is no signal either, your code has been rewritten into a [state machine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56587815/11683).

Comment: @GSerg of course there is a thread.  There is not a 1:1 mapping from Task to thread, but a task can only make progress by running its code on some thread (note: maybe not the same thread at every step of the same task) that's executing an event loop (task continuations can map to Windows messages and run on a thread with a GUI message pump, or to threadpool jobs and run on a threadpool thread, or a few other possibilities).

Comment: But a process must have a thread; if the last thread exits the process does too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess it is because the application thread is finished its job and OS just cleans everything up about our program

This is correct. Any remaining work after the process has exited is skipped.

> Now what happens to the application/main thread when it hits the first Task.Delay. As far as I know it should just abandon that thread to free resources and wait for a signal when that task is completed but that cannot happen because if that happens then the application just exists with code 0

Since you are using `async Task Main` the process will only exit after the returned task is completed. Conceptually the framework does `.GetResult()` on the returned task. Note that your `async Task Main` is not the *actual* entry point, that will be some hidden method generated by the framework to do the blocking and any other stuff that needs to be done.

You could essentially replicate the thing `async Task Main` does by writing

```
void Main()
{
     MainAsync().Wait()
}
async Task MainAsync(){
   ...
}
```

Note that the main thread in a console program is not the same as a thread pool thread. The main thread cannot run thread pool task. But this might be an implementation detail that could be subject to change.

However, both the main thread an any thread pool threads have the same threading *context*, meaning anything after `await` may run on the thread pool. This is different to UI programs where the UI thread has an *ui context*, so anything after an await is run on the UI thread.

> Who signals the thread that the task is done and who is listening for this signal and how?

The OS communicates with the process via messages, So when a `Task.Delay` elapses the OS will send a message telling the process to continue where it left of. This lets the task continue where it left of (on a thread pool thread, since the main thread is blocked), do any remaining work, and finally mark the task as completed, signaling the main thread to unblock, allowing the process to exit.

I would suggest reading a book on OS design if you are interested in the exact implementation details, since that is something outside my area of expertise.

Comment: Thanks for your time and answer. I've seen the IL code that is generated from the last example and I guess that what calls the main function is where the answer lies. But after reading your answer multiple times I still didn't figure out what happens to the main thread while awaiting the result of delay. It cannot die. If the top level async basically calls .GetResult, you mean that thread is blocked? This cannot be the case is it? There is something missing here.

Comment: @m.stm "you mean that thread is blocked" - Yes, that is exactly the case. Sorry if not making it more clear. If you want to see for yourself you can simply increase the delays a bit, and break your program in the debugger. You should see the main thread being blocked, waiting for the task to complete. But note that this may be version/platform dependent.

Comment: so top level async calls are equivalent to calling `.GetResult()` on them? If not then what is the difference?

Comment: @m.stm yes. You should get similar result if you changed your first example to `Delay().Wait()` to block until the task has completed.

Comment: That is for sure true and I know that. But resource management is different in async and sync. What I meant is that is the resource management/behavior the same as using `.GetResult` in top level async code.

Comment: @m.stm I'm not sure what you mean by resource management. The only significant reasource would be threads, and that should be the same. I.e. the main thread will exist for the duration of the process, and any continuation will be run on threadpool threads. While waiting for the delay the, main thread will be blocked, and no other thread used, except possibly threads internal to the runtime.

Comment: Thanks, this last comment answered my question perfectly. I'm going to keep this question open for a little bit more time so if others wanted to say anything they do. Then I'll accept your answer.  >_<

Comment: But @hina10531 said "It’s technically not right to say there’s no alive threads any more. It’s just in idle state, they are ready to work as soon as a work item is enqueued". Which one is true?

Comment: @m.stm Hina10531 claim that the main thread becomes "free" is false, as is evident by just using a debugger and inspecting the threads while awaiting something. It is not a thread pool thread. It cannot run work scheduled on the thread pool. But the details are really not that important, the important bit is the behavior of your program, not how the framework manages resources that you have no control of anyway.  It is also possible for the details to change between framework versions, since the framework only guarantees behavior.

Comment: Can you please include these comment discussions in your answer? I think this would help a bunch.

Comment: *"The main thread cannot run thread pool task. But this might be an implementation detail that could be subject to change."* -- I find it highly unlikely that the main thread of a Console application will ever be owned by the `ThreadPool`. The `ThreadPool` has background threads, and a process without at least one foreground thread terminates immediately.

Answer (score 0):

A very verbose, step by step illustration might help you better for this topic.

## **The first example.**

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("before M");
    Delay();
    Console.WriteLine("after M");
}

async void Delay()
{
    Console.WriteLine("before D1");
    await Task.Delay(100);
    Console.WriteLine("after D1 - 1 ");
    await Task.Delay(100);
    Console.WriteLine("after D1 - 2");
    await Task.Delay(100);
    Console.WriteLine("after D1 - 3");
    await Task.Delay(100);
    Console.WriteLine("after D1 - last");
}

Main();

Console.WriteLine("exited main");
```

**Q. First of all what actually happens in the first example**

**A.**

1. Main thread calls `Main();`
2. Main thread runs `Console.WriteLine("before M");`
3. Main thread calls `Delay()` method.
4. Main thread runs `Console.WriteLine("before D1");`
5. Main thread calls `await Task.Delay(100);` but it schedules a task and immediately becomes free, the rest of the code is upto the continuation task which will be picked up by thread pool thread after this `Task.Delay(100);`
6. Main thread continues to run `Console.WriteLine("after M")` in the `Main()` method body.
7. Main thread runs the last `Console.WriteLine("exited main");`
8. The continuation can't happen becuase the program is terminated.

## **The second example**

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("before M");
    Delay();
    Console.WriteLine("after M");
}

async void Delay()
{
    Console.WriteLine("before D1");
    await Task.Delay(100);
    Console.WriteLine("after D1 - 1 ");
    await Task.Delay(100);
    Console.WriteLine("after D1 - 2");
    await Task.Delay(100);
    Console.WriteLine("after D1 - 3");
    await Task.Delay(100);
    Console.WriteLine("after D1 - last");
}

Main();
while (true)
{
}

Console.WriteLine("exiting application");
```

**Q. What happens to all those async tasks**

**A.**

1. Main thread calls `Main();`
2. Main thread runs `Console.WriteLine("before M")`;
3. Main thread calls `Delay()` method
4. Main thread runs `Console.WriteLine("before D1")`;
5. Main thread calls `await Task.Delay(100);` but it schedules a task and immediately becomes free, the rest of the code is upto the continuation task which will be picked up by a thread pool thread after this `Task.Delay(100)`;
6. Main thread continues to run `Console.WriteLine("after M")`;
7. Main thread is trapped inside of while loop.
8. Timer elapsed. A callback is enqueued and the continuation is picked up by a thread in the thread pool.
9. A thread runs `Console.WriteLine("after D1 - 1 ")`;
10. A thread calls `await Task.Delay(100);` but it schedules a task and immediately becomes free, the rest of the code is upto the continuation task which will be picked up by a thread pool thread after this `Task.Delay(100)`;
11. Timer elapsed. A callback is enqueued and the continuation is picked up by a thread in the thread pool.
12. B thread runs `Console.WriteLine("after D1 - 2 ")`;
13. B thread calls `await Task.Delay(100)`; does the same thing...
14. Timer elapsed. A callback is enqueued, another thread kicks in
15. C thread runs `Console.WriteLine("after D1 - 3 ")`;
16. C thread calls `await Task.Delay(100)`; does the same thing...
17. Timer elapsed. A callback is enqueued, another thread kicks in
18. D thread runs `Console.WriteLine("after D1 - last ")`;
19. D thread calls `await Task.Delay(100)`; does the same thing...
20. Continuation is done here, `Delay()` method is finished.
21. Main thread still in the loop, never exiting the program.

## **The third example**

```
async Task Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("before M");
    await Delay();
    Console.WriteLine("after M");
}

async Task Delay()
{
    Console.WriteLine("before D1");
    await Task.Delay(100);
    Console.WriteLine("after D1 - 1 ");
    await Task.Delay(100);
    Console.WriteLine("after D1 - 2");
    await Task.Delay(100);
    Console.WriteLine("after D1 - 3");
    await Task.Delay(100);
    Console.WriteLine("after D1 - last");
}

await Main();

Console.WriteLine("exiting application");
```

**Q. So what happens to this thread? What happens to the TOP-LEVEL caller of an async functions thread? Who signals the thread that the task is done and who is listening for this signal and how?**

**Who signals?** : If it's a true I/O, an overlapped signal will be raised and IOCP thread will get the signal. But in this example, `Task.Delay` doesn't raise the signal, the timer just enqueues a callback when 100ms has been elapsed.

**A.**

1. Main thread calls `Main();`
2. Main thread runs `Console.WriteLine("before M");`
3. Main thread calls `Delay()` method;
4. Main thread runs `Console.WriteLine("before D1");`
5. Main thread calls `await Task.Delay(100);` but it schedules a task and immediately becomes free, the rest of the code is upto the continuation task which will be picked up by thread pool thread after this `Task.Delay(100);`
6. Timer elapsed. A callback is enqueued and the continuation is picked up by a thread in the thread pool.
7. A thread runs `Console.WriteLine("after D1 - 1 ");`
8. A thread calls `await Task.Delay(100);` but it schedules a task and immediately becomes free, the rest of the code is upto the continuation task which will be picked up by thread pool thread after this `Task.Delay(100);`
9. Timer elapsed. A callback is enqueued and the continuation is picked up by a thread in the thread pool.
10. B thread runs `Console.WriteLine("after D1 - 2 ");`
11. B thread calls `await Task.Delay(100);` does the same thing...
12. Timer elapsed. A callback is enqueued, another thread kicks in
13. C thread runs `Console.WriteLine("after D1 - 3 ");`
14. C thread calls `await Task.Delay(100);` does the same thing...
15. Timer elapsed. A callback is enqueued, another thread kicks in
16. D thread runs `Console.WriteLine("after D1 - last ");`
17. D thread calls `await Task.Delay(100);` does the same thing...
18. D thread goes on running `Console.WriteLine("after M");`
19. D thread runs `Console.WriteLine("exiting application");`

You may want to add the thread identifier when you print the logs.

`Console.WriteLine($"{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} {Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread} exiting application")`

In console program, the main thread has `false` on `IsThreadPoolThread` property and will be printed as `false`. You will easily get to know who runs what by adding those identifiers.

And I want you to know that the continuation may run on a same thread pool thread, when all the other threads are idle. In this illustration, all continuations are picked up by different thread pool thread, but this is not guaranteed, it depends on how currently busy the thread pool is.

You should also understand `synchronization context` as well. Put it simply, the continuation will be executed on the caller thread when `synchronization context` exists and you run the task without `ConfigureAwait(false)`. A console application doesn't have `synchronization context` by default. If your example was an UI app, I would have illustrated those steps very differently.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort in the answer. Only in the last example I see the word Main Thread `waits` for ***. By wait what do we mean here? Main thread is now blocked? If that's the case then continuation blocks cannot ever run in the main thread, they are forced to run in a thread from threadpool. I mean if there are other things that are queued to main thread, they cannot run now right? If its true async, main thread should be freed. But if it gets freed then application dies. so top level async calls are equivalent to calling `.GetResult()` on them? If not then what is the difference?

Comment: `wait` I mentioned above means it's ready to execute another task that it may pick up later on. I think the expression makes people confused, so I got rid of the sentence. `GetResult()` is completely different thing. `await` is a keyword and it allows the code to wait for an asynchronous operation to complete before continuing execution. `GetResult()` is a method of the `Task` that retrieves the result of a completed task synchronously. `GetResult()` can definitely result in blocking a thread.

Comment: So between 5 and 6, there no alive threads for this console application right? Is this even possible?

Comment: It’s technically not right to say there’s no alive threads any more. It’s just in idle state, they are ready to work as soon as a work item is enqueued.